# some time can't access NSmanagedObject returned form fetchResultController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have been struggling several days because of some weird overreleased.
My tableView is little bit different type  so can't use `NSFetchControllerDelegate`.
Actually three thumbnail views in each row which can toucable.
So can't use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The problem is after execution patch.  The first access to `NSManagedObject` returned from 
fetchedResultController objectAt indexPath works ... but second try  make access to deallocated object which mean is object is already overreleased.

But the more make me crazy is exact same function in `TableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath` is work always.

```
#pragma mark AlbumListViewCellSelectionDelegate  ==> my custom delegate method**** 

- (void)albumContentsTableViewCell:(AlbumLibViewCell *)cell
    selectedPhotoAtIndexType:(NSUInteger)index {
//[self fetch];

NSLog(@"select !!!! %i",index);

lastSelectedRow=cell.rowNumber;


//[selectedAssets addObject:[assets objectAtIndex:(lastSelectedRow * imageNoPerRow) + index]];
int selectId =(lastSelectedRow * imageNoPerRow) + index;

if(albumCount >=(selectId+1)){


AlbumTag * album = (AlbumTag *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectId inSection:0]] ;
//scrollView 
    AutoScrollViewController *detailViewController =[[AutoScrollViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;


    detailViewController.selectedMoments = [album.moments allObjects];==> first work but overrelease every second try 
    detailViewController.initPhotoNumber = 0;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

same function but every time no problem

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AlbumLibViewCell";

AlbumLibViewCell *cell = (AlbumLibViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumLibViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tmpCell;
    tmpCell = nil;
}

cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor  blackColor];
cell.rowNumber = indexPath.row;
cell.selectionDelegate = self;

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger firstPhotoInCell = indexPath.row * imageNoPerRow;
NSUInteger lastPhotoInCell  = firstPhotoInCell + imageNoPerRow;

if (albumCount <= firstPhotoInCell) {
    NSLog(@"We are out of range, asking to start with photo %d but we only have %d", firstPhotoInCell, albumCount);
    return nil;
}

NSUInteger currentPhotoIndex = 0;
NSUInteger lastPhotoIndex = MIN(lastPhotoInCell, albumCount);
for (firstPhotoInCell ; firstPhotoInCell + currentPhotoIndex < lastPhotoIndex ; currentPhotoIndex++) {

    AlbumTag *albumCell = (AlbumTag *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:firstPhotoInCell + currentPhotoIndex inSection:0]];
    UIImage *thumbnail = albumCell.rpeMomentThumbnail;

    NSArray *moments =  [albumCell.moments allObjects]; ===> every time works fine
```

Any idea for this situation might be help
appreciate in advance all.

Comment: What line in the code generates the error?

Comment: what is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like objects being passed into detailViewController are being released but not retained. You should turn on NSZombies to debug this. If that doesn't work you can track your allocation history using the ObjectAlloc instrument in Instruments.